# How to git clone or checkout the most recently modified branch?

Tags: git

I'm working with some projects that use `master` as the stable branch and use feature branches for feature development. I'd like to integrate against the most recent work. Is there a way to have `git` clone or checkout the most recently modified branch?

Comment: Because Git can represent a non-linear history, it does not make sense to integrate against "recent" work, because each individual branch may be arbitrarily different from any other branch. Typically, your project should have a branching strategy which tells you into which branch your code should be integrated.

Comment: @chepner I'm working on a system that lacks that assumption and attempts to be generally useful for all branching strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following `git rev-list --all | head -1 | xargs git name-rev` to get the most recent (in terms of time) commit branch.